ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rtmidi when installing MAGENTA
Please, help, when I try pip install magenta it gives me that error
I tried upgrade and downgrade the python versions, the pip versions, the Microsoft Visual C++ but it still doesn't work. I saw comments, that MAGENTA doesn't work on python 3.8 and latest, but this error I get on python 3.6  I tried install rtmidi and after that magenta. I tried to reinstall all my python software, python, pip, pycharm etc. But it still not working.
[error, which I get, when try pip install magenta]
(https://i.sstatic.net/rRKu3DkZ.jpg)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-rtmidi
  Building wheel for python-rtmidi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x7zn0gr0'
       cwd: C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1brc3z2\python-rtmidi\
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\midiconstants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\midiutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  running build_ext
  building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rtmidi
  Running setup.py clean for python-rtmidi
Failed to build python-rtmidi



Installing collected packages: python-rtmidi, magenta
  Attempting uninstall: python-rtmidi
    Found existing installation: python-rtmidi 1.5.8
    Uninstalling python-rtmidi-1.5.8:
      Successfully uninstalled python-rtmidi-1.5.8
    Running setup.py install for python-rtmidi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v1l190hu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\python-rtmidi'
         cwd: C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1brc3z2\python-rtmidi\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\midiconstants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\midiutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    running build_ext
    building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of python-rtmidi
  Moving to c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\python_rtmidi-1.5.8.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\~ython_rtmidi-1.5.8.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\rtmidi\
   from C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\~tmidi
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1brc3z2\\python-rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v1l190hu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\python-rtmidi' Check the logs for full command output.

Tell me please how can I install MAGENTA correct?
